# ASP.NET MVC4 Web API & Session variables

Tags: android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

In my asp.net mvc4 project, I am using ApiControllers to serve both web clients and mobile clients. To secure the web services, I am using the [Authorize] annotation. 
So for now, the web client is working fine. However, when I tend to invoke some Web API from a mobile application (e.g. Android), I got an error.
when I looked back at code snippet:

```
   [Authorize]
    public List<double> GetSomeInfo(int param1, string param2)
        {
           User user = SessionData.CurrentUser;
           // do something using user.UserId
           // ....

        }
```

Session Data does hold user connected properties only when he is connected to the Web App. But in the case of mobile clients, Session Data is null. So, is there any appropriate method to resolve this problem. 
In my opinion, I think that userId should be provided as a parameter for any Web API that may need it to do achieve some treatment.
What do you think ?

Comment: Have you checked out [IdentityModel](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45)?

Comment: which authentication you are using? Form Authentication will not work for mobile client, consider using basic authentication or digit authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about two different things :

- **Session**

As Darrel said, Web Api was not design to support Asp.net Session. HTTP and Rest Services are stateless – and as a result each HTTP request **should carry enough information by itself** for its recipient to process it to be in complete harmony with the stateless nature of HTTP.
So, do not rely on Session Variables, but add more paramters in your request.
Of course, there are a way to use session in Web Api, I suggest you to to use it.

- **Authentication**

Because working with only paramaters ( such as UserId, AccountId, ...) is not very secure, you have to use Authentication and Authorization. I highly suggest you to read the [security section](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api) in asp.net web api web site. Web Api support many authentications (Basic, OAuth, Windows, Custom, ...). You have to choose what is the best for you.

Comment: Yes you are absoluty right, When I posted this question, I was still learning about MVC4 and Web api, But I know I have a clearer idea, and I did exactly what you've recommanded.. respecting the stateless definition of Web api and for security, I used Basic authentication..Now Web and Mobile clients are both working fine

Answer (score 0):

Web API was not designed to support sessions as they are a HTTP anti-pattern.  You can get the currently authenticated user by accessing Thread.CurrentPrincipal if you have setup the necessary authentication mechanisms.

Comment: I don't seem to understand what you are talking about, ca you please provide me with a link or some code snippets ?